# Angular HttpErrorResponse error properties with TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

I'm trying to display a custom error message to the user based on what is coming from our API. My issue is that the HttpErrorResponse from @angular/common/http has the property error set as any or null and the custom error code sent from our API is a property of the type any error object.

I'm trying to access the property called *errorCode* like this, but keep getting errors from ts and eslint on unsafe access on an any value.

```
private getErrorMessage(error: HttpErrorResponse): string | undefined {
        return = ApiErrorCodes[error?.error?.errorCode];
}
```

Rewriting the HttpErrorResponse type with explicit error object seems a bit risky as the properties might vary. Is there a workaround this except disabling the rules?

Comment: TypeScript only performs static type checking at compile time! The generated JavaScript, which is what actually runs when you run your code, does not know anything about the types.

Comment: `error?.error?.errorCode as String`